# activeadmin "Object doesn't support this property or method" on admin/login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4x66oH4mt4&list=PLDmvslp_VR0xlwr5lAx2PDsZLu7oIOhpX&index=28), but I got stuck on an this error:

**ExecJS::ProgramError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new**

```
Showing    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-78324a83fa01/app/views/layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb where line #9 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Rails.root: c:/Sites/myrubyblog
```

- **Ruby directory:** C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0
- **My app directory:** C:\Sites\myrubyblog

Line #9 in active_admin_logged_out.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag style, options %>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What version of Rails? ActiveAdmin is not compatible with Rails 4 or 5.

Comment: Ohh... Rails 4.2.5.1 :/ 
Any solution?

Comment: Yes: use something else.

Comment: what is in line Line #9 in active_admin_logged_out.html.erb: